# Drawing a texture at the end of a trace (crosshair?) UDK

Tags: game-mechanics, udk, unreal

I'm trying to draw a crosshair at the end of my trace.

If my crosshair does not hit a pawn or static mesh (ex, just a skybox) then the crosshair stays locked on a certain point at that actor - I want to say its origin.

Ex: Run across a pawn, then it turns yellow and stays on that pawn. If it runs across the skybox, then it stays at one point on the box. Weird?

How can I get my crosshair to stay consistent? I've included two images for reference, to help illustrate.

Note: The wrench is actually my crosshair. The "X" is just a debug crosshair. Ignore that.
/// [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMJsu.png) ///
/// [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZRsw.jpg) ///

```
/***************************************************************************
* Draws the crosshair
***************************************************************************/
function bool CheckCrosshairOnFriendly()
{ 
local float             CrosshairSize;
local vector            HitLocation, HitNormal, StartTrace, EndTrace, ScreenPos;
local actor             HitActor;
local MyWeapon          W;
local Pawn              MyPawnOwner;

/** Sets the PawnOwner */
MyPawnOwner = Pawn(PlayerOwner.ViewTarget); 
/** Sets the Weapon */
W = MyWeapon(MyPawnOwner.Weapon);   

/** If we don't have an owner, then get out of the function */
if ( MyPawnOwner == None )
{
    return false;
}   

/** If we have a weapon... */
if ( W != None)
{
    /** Values for the trace */ 
    StartTrace = W.InstantFireStartTrace();
    EndTrace = StartTrace + W.MaxRange() * vector(PlayerOwner.Rotation);
    HitActor = MyPawnOwner.Trace(HitLocation, HitNormal, EndTrace, StartTrace, true, vect(0,0,0),, TRACEFLAG_Bullet);   
    DrawDebugLine(StartTrace, EndTrace, 100,100,100,);

    /** Projection for the crosshair to convert 3d coords into 2d */ 
    ScreenPos = Canvas.Project(HitLocation); 

    /** If we haven't hit any actors... */
    if ( Pawn(HitActor) == None )
    {
        HitActor = (HitActor == None) ? None : Pawn(HitActor.Base);
    }
}

/** If our trace hits a pawn... */
if ((Pawn(HitActor) == None))
{
    /** Draws the crosshair for no one - Grey*/
    CrosshairSize = 28 * (Canvas.ClipY / 768) * (Canvas.ClipX /1024);
    Canvas.SetDrawColor(100,100,128,255);
    Canvas.SetPos(ScreenPos.X - (CrosshairSize * 0.5f), ScreenPos.Y -(CrosshairSize * 0.5f));
    Canvas.DrawTile(class'UTHUD'.default.AltHudTexture, CrosshairSize, CrosshairSize, 600, 262, 28, 27);    
    return false;
}   

    /** Draws the crosshair for friendlies - Yellow */
    CrosshairSize = 28 * (Canvas.ClipY / 768) * (Canvas.ClipX /1024);
    Canvas.SetDrawColor(255,255,128,255);
    Canvas.SetPos(ScreenPos.X - (CrosshairSize * 0.5f), ScreenPos.Y -(CrosshairSize * 0.5f));
    Canvas.DrawTile(class'UTHUD'.default.AltHudTexture, CrosshairSize, CrosshairSize, 600, 262, 28, 27);
    return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't hitting anything, your HitLocation will be vect(0,0,0). In cases like this, you just need a:

```
if(HitActor == none)
{
   HitLocation = EndTrace;
}
```